# Energy loss in Fluid flow

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, potential, bernoulli-equation

In a constant diameter, ground level pipe of substantial length to reflect a pressure drop of dP, how would the loss of energy be accounted for?

The assumption would be that kinetic and potential energy do not change across the length of pipe

Comment: Pressure is energy per unit volume.

Comment: It would be accounted for by viscous friction (viscous dissipation if mechanical energy to internal energy).

Comment: Yes, P is PE/Volume so when dP occurs along pipe length (even on water at 1Cps), that volume must do work presumably dissipated as heat?

Comment: Yes, it's dissipated as heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "open system" version of the first law of thermodynamics applied to the adiabatic, steady state flow of the fluid through the pipe, we have that:  $$\Delta h=0$$where h is the enthalpy per unit mass of the fluid, and the $\Delta$ signifies the difference between the entrance and exit of the pipe.  If the fluid is incompressible, then $\Delta h$ is related to the temperature change and the pressure change of the fluid by:  $$\Delta h=C_p\Delta T+v\Delta P$$ where v is the specific volume and $C_p$ is the specific heat capacity.  Therefore, from these equations, it follows that:
$$\Delta T=-\frac{v}{C_p}\Delta P$$
where $-\Delta P$ is the pressure drop in the pipe, which is the result of viscous/turbulent friction for the flow.  The latter can be determined by the Darcy-Weissbach correlation.  The temperature rise $\Delta T$ would be referred to in this case as viscous heating, and would be the result of viscous dissipation of mechanical energy.

Comment: Using the 1st Law and some basic assumptions for reasonable water flow in a 100’ long 2” ID length of pipe, the temperature drop I believe you predict here is approximate 0.1 degF per linear foot of pipe - very reasonable and hardly detectable if all energy is dissipated as heat - further, it has always been my assumption that other forms of energy dissipation may accompany the heat loss such as sound & vibration frequently present is type of system?

Comment: It’s not a temperature drop, it’s a temperature rise, and 0.1 F per foot sounds very high to me.  What kind of total pressure drop did you estimate?

Comment: Yes that was rise & I used 150’ of head loss per 1000’ of 2” pipe assuming 60F water and fluid velocity of around 7 ft/sec

Comment: For that pressure gradient , I predict a much lower temperature rise.  Let’s see your calculation.

Comment: I used dT= -{ (0.016 cu.ft/lbm / 1 BTU/lbm-F) * (4.33 psi*144) =0.1 degF per 100’ of 2” pipe .. looking closer my ballpark of 100’ head loss per 1000’ line would reflect 75 gpm for Sch40  - all reasonable but the mistake is glaring now

Comment: there is no way ambient water will see a 10 degF temperature increase across 100’ of 2” line with a low velocity of 7 ft/sec .. must have an error somewhere

Comment: You screwed up the units.  You need to convert ft-lb to BTU, or vice versa.

Comment: That’s it alright - dimensional analysis correct but conversion factor itself absent in rush .. the numbers makes sense; throw in more P drop, differing density, Cp or viscosity and things can get interesting with Temperature rise - all with 1/2mv^2 and mgh constant